# WPSL-AJAX-FUNCTIONS.PHP in not reading Global Vairable values properly

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Okay I am utilising the plugin Wordpress Store Locator & as per my customised requirement this plugin works great; only bottleneck I'm receiving is that I am unable to successfully pass the value of the present Page to it.

i.e. for eg.

If URL is www.example.com/shop/wpsl/

My requirement is to utilise wpsl i.e substring of /shop/wpsl

I am somehow not able to extract it.

//Code Removed

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Okay so found the problem.

I've a file wpsl-ajax-functions.php , it is not reading values of global variable if that global variable is getting its value from another variable (irrespective of the fact whether it is $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or $org_unit). But if I manually give the global variable a value the same is being stored.

My Latest Wordpress Template **functions.php** looks something like this :-

```
global $org_unit;
if( strcmp(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1,4),"shop") == 0) {
$len = 5 - strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) -1;
$org = strtoupper(stripslashes(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],6)));
$org = substr($org,0,-1);
$org_unit = $org;
}
else
{
$org_unit = "";
}
$GLOBALS[ 'to_trunc' ] = "'FOOD".$org_unit."'"; //FOOD is mentioned to test the output as the variable $org_unit also contains FOOD
```

On getting its output in the Header.php, Footer.php via echo gives 'FOODFOOD' where the later FOOD is from $org_unit variable.

While in my **wpsl-ajax-functions.php** the following code

```
$qr_Fax = "AND FAX LIKE (".$GLOBALS[ 'to_trunc' ].")";
```

is only having value FOOD so that the $qr_Fax variable gets the value 'FOOD'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I am somehow not able to extract it.*". Why? What happened? Did you get an error? An empty value? NULL? FALSE? From where? The option? Have you checked the DB?

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes I'm getting a NULL(blank) value, whereas $GLOBALS[ 'to_trunc' ] is giving output when I'm performing echo on the header while the same is defined in Head(template/head.php)

Comment: @h2ooooooo See the Question now , have edited it, post diving further & investigating.